# access std::array<std::array> elements in c++

Tags: c++

I need to access elements inside an array of arrays.

My code used to be like this:

```
byte var0[8]; // array of 8 bytes
byte var1[8];
byte var2[8];

c.read(100, 1000, 8, &var0); // reading 8 bytes starting from address 1000 and saving them in var0
c.read(100, 3700, 8, &var1);
c.read(100, 6400, 8, &var2);
```

everything worked fine but since I need to declare not just 3 arrays but 60 instead I wanted to write a better version of my code.

I thought of writing it like this:

```
std::array<std::array<byte, 8>, 60> arr;

for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    c.read(100, 1000 + (2700 * i), 8, arr[i]); // trying to save 8 bytes inside arr[i]
}
```

I thought of writing an array of arrays of 8 bytes each.

Then I'm populating them using a for loop.
Is it correct to write arr[i] inside the loop?

And how can I access the values now?

I used to write something like this before:

```
std::cout << getBitAt(var0, 1, 2) << \n; // printing the 3rd bit of the 2nd byte of var0
```

Now I want to do the same with the array of the arrays I created, i.e. something like this:

```
std::cout << getBitAt(arr[0], 1, 2) << \n;
```

**EDIT**: the definition of the read method is:

```
int read(int DBNumber, int Start, int Size, void *pUsrData);
```

it's a method from a library called snap7

I tried the solution:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    c.read(100, 1000 + (2700 * i), 8, arr[i].data());
}
```

but I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘PLC::GetBitAt(std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 8>, 60>::value_type&, int, int)’
```

So I tried (don't know if it is correct) to use:

```
std::cout << getBitAt(arr[0].data(), 1, 2) << \n;
```

but I'm now getting the error:

```
 error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, std::basic_ostream<char>&>’
```

the method GetBitAt is:

```
bool getBitAt(byte buffer[], int pos, int bit) {
  byte mask[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80};
  if(bit < 0) bit = 0;
  if(bit > 7) bit = 7;
  return (buffer[pos] & mask[bit]) != 0;
}
```

**SOLVED**:

`c.read(100, 1000 + (2700 * i), 8, arr[i].data());`

This solution worked.

I had another problem in the code that was causing the last error.
Thanks to everyone

Comment: What is the definition of function `c.read`?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/data so `c.read(100, 1000 + (2700 * i), 8, arr[i].data());` and `getBitAt(arr[0]->data(), 1, 2)` (note you din't provide declaration of `getBitAt`).

Comment: see edit please. I got another error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it correct to write arr[i] inside the loop?

Yes, it is correct to write `arr[i]` inside loops. `arr[i]` is the i'th element of `arr`.

> I get an error, i.e. "`no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 8>, 60>::value_type {aka std::array<unsigned char, 8>}’ to ‘byte* {aka unsigned char*}’`"

This means that `read` doesn't accept `std::array` as an argument. `arr[i]` is a `std::array`, so you cannot pass it like that. You can use `arr[i].data()` instead (or `&arr[i][0]` if you prefer) to get a pointer to the data. Unlike a regular array, `std::array` does not decay to a pointer to first element.

> And how can I access the values now?

You can access the sub arrays using `arr[i]` and elements of the sub arrays using `arr[i][j]`.

Comment: `arr[i]` is a `std::array` object, and it looks like the `read` function expects a pointer. So `arr[i]` wouldn't be correct.

Comment: @interjay depends on whether `read` expects *only* a pointer or not. There could be an overload for std::array. Or it could be a template. arr[i] is not wrong in general. Whether something else or something additional is needed here is unknown.

Comment: The original code passed a pointer to `read`. OP hasn't shown its prototype but there's no reason to assume there's an overload for `std::array`.

Comment: in fact if I write std::cout << getBitAt(arr[0], 1, 2) << \n; I get an error, i.e. "no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::array<std::array<unsigned char, 8>, 60>::value_type {aka std::array<unsigned char, 8>}’ to ‘byte* {aka unsigned char*}’ "

Comment: `arr[i]` is the (i+1)' th element of the array

Comment: @GerardoZinno If `arr[0]` is the zeroeth element, then `arr[i]` it the `i`'th element

Comment: @eerorika to me arr[0] is the first element of the array, but at the end I guess it just a way of seeing things. It would be confusing saying that arr[1] is the first/1-th element of the array

Comment: @eerorika it works now! the arr[i].data() works fine...thank you

Comment: @GerardoZinno yeah, "first" "second" etc. element mean 0th 1th etc to me. Zeroeth meaning same as first.